# Find integer in list with Array.exists()

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of integers:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
```

How can I find out if a number such as the number `1` exists in this array without doing a for loop?

I saw that C# has an `Array.Exists(T)` method but I am not sure how to use it. If this is a good way to do it then I would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# arrays can be used in LINQ expressions, you can do this:

```
bool hasOne = a.Any(n => (n == 4));
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` in order for this to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Better to user `Contains` or `Any` but you asked for `Exists` so:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
```

`Exists`:

```
bool a = Array.Exists(arr, elem => elem == 1); // true
bool b = Array.Exists(arr, elem => elem == 5); // false
```

`Contains`:

```
  bool a = arr.Contains(1); // true
  bool b = arr.Contains(5); // false
```

`Any`:

```
 bool a = arr.Any(elem => elem == 1); // true
 bool b = arr.Any(elem => elem == 5); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) Contains you can check for the existence of int,

```
var intVar = 1;
var exists = a.Contains(intVar);
```

Comment: @marifemac the best way to check it is to try it yourself! https://dotnetfiddle.net/0PR3iT